# Why cannot I display user List?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a Person.class with parameters: name, age, email and I have a jsp form for adding new user into ArrayList

```
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/addclientform.jsp")
public class AddClientServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private PersonStorage personlist1 = new PersonStorage();

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("age"));
        String email = req.getParameter("email");

        Person person = new Person(name, age, email);
        personlist1.addPerson(person);

        req.setAttribute("list", personlist1);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("clientList.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    }
}

<html>
<head>
<title>Clien Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="personlist">
            <tr>
                <td>${personlist.name}</td>
                <td>${personlist.age}</td>
                <td>${personlist.email}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <form name="home" action="home.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="back">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I want to see all users I cannot do this.
Where I made a mistake?

Comment: This is my clientList.jsp
<html>
<head>
    <title>Clien Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="personlist">
        <tr>
            <td>${personlist.name}</td>
            <td>${personlist.age}</td>
            <td>${personlist.email}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
<form name="home" action="home.jsp" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="back">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You can [edit] your question with that code. It would be more readable. Is `Person` have getters for those members?

Comment: Yes, person has

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following directive at the top of the page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Comment: Well why don't you post a valid *complete* question so no one else has to waste their time trying to help.